# Fuzzy Logic on chosen dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/318/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#campaign_list').chosen({
        no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });
    $('#campaign_list').css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '30px',
        'border-radius': '2px'
    });
    $('#campaign_list_chosen').css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '30px',
        'border-radius': '2px'
    });
    $('#camp_list').chosen({
        no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });
    $('#camp_list').css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '30px',
        'border-radius': '2px'
    });
    $('#camp_list_chosen').css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '30px',
        'border-radius': '2px'
    });
    $("#campaign_list_chosen").find("input").on('keyup', function () {
        var final_list = '';
        var srch_array = new Array();
        var srch_option = new Array();
        var list_option = new Array();
        var str_srch = $(this).val();
        var final_list_option = new Array();
        srch_array = str_srch.split(" ");
        var srch_array_lengh = srch_array.length;
        $("#campaign_list option").each(function () {
            list_option.push($(this).val());
        });
        for (var lo = 0; lo < list_option.length; lo++) {
            var count_match = 0;
            for (var sa = 0; sa < srch_array_lengh; sa++) {
                if (list_option[lo].toLowerCase().indexOf(srch_array[sa]) >= 0) {
                    count_match++;
                }
            }
            if (count_match == srch_array_lengh) {
                final_list_option.push(list_option[lo]);
            }
        }
        $("#campaign_list_chosen").find("ul").html('');
        for (var fo = 0; fo < final_list_option.length; fo++) {
            final_list = final_list + '<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">' + final_list_option[fo] + '</li>';
        }
        $(".chosen-results").html(final_list);
    });
});
```

I have added a fuzzy logic on the jquery dropdown..

But the main problem is that, if I type something in the textbox and select the option from the filtered list, then the second options gets selected always.

However if I type nothing and select from the drpdown, then the corressponding value gets selected.

For example type "us camp" in the text box and select the option thats being shown..

you will see only second options being selected.

How can i solve it..

Comment: Do you think the constant `data-option-array-index="1"` might have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't have any idea... its just that after i filter the option, always the desired option are getting selected

Answer (score 1):

I think problems are the position you assign in loops

```
for(var lo = 0; lo < list_option.length; lo++)
```

and

```
for(var sa = 0; sa <srch_array_lengh; sa++)
```

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/322/) is what you want?

Comment: Its not about that....i cant select any option from the filtered data.... its always selects the second one

Comment: in my fiddle example data is selected correctly... check it... http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/322/

Comment: type "us camp".... it states no option.... in my fiddle type "us camp"... it will give you an option